# How to extract domain part from email address column in Python without .com

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, email

I have column marked as email in my dataset
and I tried using `df['email'].str.split('@').str[1]` but it gives me `'gmail.com'` and I want **Gmail** as output. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Add a second `split('.')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split that again on "." and then select the domain part
For example:

```
email = "example@domain.com"
domain_name = email.split('@')[1].split('.')[0] #This will be "domain"
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahan. I tried (df['email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.rsplit('.').str[0] and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want Gmail part, you can split the split that you do. Something like `df['email'].str.split('@').str[1].split(".")[0]`

Comment: Thanks @mrjamaisvu. I tried (df['email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.rsplit('.').str[0] and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to get the first part of the domain?

You can also use a regex:

```
df['email'].str.extract(r'(?<=@)([^\.]+)')
```

If you want all the subdomains except the top level domain (`abc.def` in `abc.def.com`):

```
df['email'].str.extract(r'(?<=@)(.+)\.\w+')
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway. 
I tried (df['email'].str.split('@').str[1]).str.rsplit('.').str[0] and it worked!